# Open Directory Tree in Xcode

Tags: xcode

Is there a way to open a directory tree in Xcode like Sublime Text or VS Code or Atom? Not an Xcode project; not something that can be built -> simply opening an Xcode project. All I want is to use the "Open Quickly" feature of Xcode as a way to search files.

I am not looking for autocomplete, indexing, etc. Just need my Xcode to be a text editor.

Wondering if this is at all possible.

Comment: > What are you really trying to do

I am trying to open it in Xcode. 

> Since you know Sublime Text (or TextMate or whatever) will do this, why do you need to misuse Xcode to do it?

Why do you claim it like it's a misuse of Xcode? I simply asked if this is possible or not. Just say no.

I don't want to use Sublime Text. I'd like to use Xcode. If I wanted to use Sublime Text, I wouldn't have made this question.

Comment: I use TextMate or (more often) BBEdit for this purpose.

Comment: Cool. Thank you.